# Binding energy per nucleon of the nucleus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, binding-energy

I'm trying to calculate the binding energy in MeV per nucleon of the nucleus for Sulphur-34. However, I am told that my calculation is wrong and that the mass of the electrons do not have to be taken into account.

How exactly would it then be calculated? Here's what I have tried:
proton mass: $1.007276$ amu
Neutron mass: $1.008665$ amu
Sulphur-34 mass: $33.9678668$ amu

Calculation:

1.$(16\cdot1.007276)+(18\cdot1.008665)+(16 \cdot0.000549)=34.28117$
2.$34.28117-33.9678668=0.3133032$
3. 1 atomic mass unit = $\frac{931.5 \mathrm{MeV}}{c^2}$
4. $[E=mc^2]=0.3133032 ×\frac{931.5 MeV}{c^2} =291.840051 (\text{total})$
$\frac{291.840051}{34}=8.583530912\mathrm{MeV}$ (per nucleon)

I would really appreciate the communities support on finding my error.

Comment: You can do this in Google: `c^2*(16*((proton mass)+(electron mass))+18*(939.5654133 MeV/c^2)-(33.9678668 u))/34 in MeV` Bizarrely, it doesn't know the neutron mass.

Answer (score 2):

> I am told that my calculation is wrong and that the mass of the electrons
> do not have to be taken into account.

Actually your calculation is correct.
You do have to take the mass of the  electrons into account.
This is because the mass used in your calculation

> Sulphur-34 mass: 33.9678668 amu

is the *atomic* mass (i.e. the whole atom, nucleus and electrons),
not the *nuclear* mass (i.e. the nucleus only, without electrons).
This number is accordance with
[Atomic Weights and Isotopic Compositions for All Elements](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/Compositions/stand_alone.pl),
which gives the *atomic* weight of the S-34 isotope as $33.967867004(47)$.

Answer (score 0):

What you did isn't wrong, it's just including the electron wont make a big difference since the binding energy of the electrons to the nucleus is minimal compared to that of the binding energy between the nucleons. I did the calculations without taking into account the electrons and i got a binding energy per nucleon which is $8.5835807 $ MeV which is very close to your own result

Comment: Could you show me this calculation?

Comment: It's exactly the same as yours. Part 1 just doesn't involve the electrons

Comment: @Stackbeans It is policy on Physics SE *not* to supply worked out solutions to question deemed to be of homework-type (which includes self-study problems).